# GCP deploy error: Creating Revision interrupted

Tags: google-cloud-run, google-cloud-build, terraform-cloud, google-cloud-deploy

While deploying to GCP using Terraform and in our YAML file we have the following section

```
# Deploy to Cloud Run
- id: 'deploy'
  name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  waitFor: ['build-image','push-image']
  entrypoint: bash
  args:
    - '-c'
    - |
      gcloud beta run services update $_SERVICE_NAME \
        '--platform=$_PLATFORM' \
        '--image=$_IMAGE_NAME' \
        --labels=managed-by=gcp-cloud-build-deploy-cloud-run,commit-sha=$COMMIT_SHA,gcb-build-id=$BUILD_ID \
        '--region=$_GCP_REGION' \
        --tag '$_REVISION' \
```

We set `WaitFor` for all previous dependencies for testing. We are getting this error:

```
Starting Step #3 - "deploy"
Step #3 - "deploy": Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
Step #3 - "deploy": Deploying...
Step #3 - "deploy": Creating Revision......interrupted
Step #3 - "deploy": Deployment failed
Step #3 - "deploy": ERROR: (gcloud.beta.run.services.update) Revision my-service-ui-00007-doq is not ready.
Finished Step #3 - "deploy"
ERROR
ERROR: build step 3 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud" failed: step exited with non-zero status:  1
```

We have tried playing around with the command line and that is showing the same error. We tried several times, so this is not a random error.
**Any idea what could cause this? Or any clue how we could investigate it?**

Comment: Can you remove that revision and tag from the YAML file and try again?

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced that if a non-ready revision has a traffic tag assigned (as can be the case when tagging the revision during e.g. deploy), subsequent deploys might fail. So best to go through the UI and remove all traffic tags from revisions which are not green. Maybe that fixes the problem. Just a guess if this could be the problem.

Christian

Answer (score 0):

Remove that revision and tag from the YAML file and try again.

Removing from YAML will help because when updating traffic, "0%" traffic was being assigned to every revision specified in the traffic field. Since this revision is not ready, any operation that is assigning traffic (even though 0%) is causing this error.